# Replace a value if null or undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to apply the `??` C# operator to JavaScript and I don't know how.
Consider this in C#:

```
int i?=null;
int j=i ?? 10;//j is now 10
```

Now I have this set up in JavaScript:

```
var options={
       filters:{
          firstName:'abc'
       } 
    };
var filter=options.filters[0]||'';//should get 'abc' here, it doesn't happen
var filter2=options.filters[1]||'';//should get empty string here, because there is only one filter
```

How do I do it correctly?

Thanks.

EDIT: I spotted half of the problem: I can't use the 'indexer' notation to objects (`my_object[0]`). Is there a way to bypass it? (I don't know the names of the filters properties beforehand and don't want to iterate over them).

Answer (score 399, accepted):

Here’s the JavaScript equivalent:

```
var i = null;
var j = i || 10; //j is now 10
```

Note that the [logical operator `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) does not return a boolean value but the first value that can be converted to *true*.

Additionally use an array of objects instead of one single object:

```
var options = {
    filters: [
        {
            name: 'firstName',
            value: 'abc'
        }
    ]
};
var filter  = options.filters[0] || '';  // is {name:'firstName', value:'abc'}
var filter2 = options.filters[1] || '';  // is ''
```

That can be accessed by index.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if 0 is a valid value of i.

Comment: If anything falsey is a potentially valid input (`0`, `false`, empty string), I would do something like this instead: `var j = (i === null) ? 10 : i;` Which will only replace `null`, rather than anything that can be evaluated to false.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for this in Groovy?

Comment: if `i` is undefined, this will throw an error. seems useless to me thus.. (?)

Comment: @phil294 `var j = (i != null ? i : 10);` should work, because `undefined` is `==` null, so `i != null` is `false` for both `null` and `undefined`.

Answer (score 55):

### ES2020 Answer

The new [Nullish Coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) Operator, is finally available on JavaScript. However, do take note of the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing). You may need to use a JavaScript compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to convert it into something more backward compatible.

According to the documentation,

> The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that
> returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is
> null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

```
const options={
  filters:{
    firstName:'abc'
  } 
};
const filter = options.filters[0] ?? '';
const filter2 = options.filters[1] ?? '';
```

This will ensure that both of your variables will have a fallback value of `''` if `filters[0]` or `filters[1]` are `null`, or `undefined`.

Do take note that the nullish coalescing operator does not return the default value for other types of falsy value such as `0` and `''`. If you wish to account for all falsy values, you should be using the OR operator `||`.

Comment: You're a genie for pointing this out. Perfect since we're not supporting IE

Answer (score 30):

## Logical nullish assignment, 2020+ solution

A new operator has been added, `??=`. This is equivalent to `value = value ?? defaultValue`.

`||=` and `&&=` are similar, links below.

This checks if left side is undefined or null, short-circuiting if already defined. If not, the left side is assigned the right-side value.

#### Basic Examples

```
let a          // undefined
let b = null
let c = false

a ??= true  // true
b ??= true  // true
c ??= true  // false

// Equivalent to
a = a ?? true
```

#### Object/Array Examples

```
let x = ["foo"]
let y = { foo: "fizz" }

x[0] ??= "bar"  // "foo"
x[1] ??= "bar"  // "bar"

y.foo ??= "buzz"  // "fizz"
y.bar ??= "buzz"  // "buzz"

x  // Array [ "foo", "bar" ]
y  // Object { foo: "fizz", bar: "buzz" }
```

#### Functional Example

```
function config(options) {
    options.duration ??= 100
    options.speed ??= 25
    return options
}

config({ duration: 555 })   // { duration: 555, speed: 25 }
config({})                  // { duration: 100, speed: 25 }
config({ duration: null })  // { duration: 100, speed: 25 }
```

[??= Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_logical_nullish_assignment) Sept 2021 - 90%

[??= Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

[||= Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment)

[&&= Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment)

Answer (score 9):

#### TLDR:

`int j=i ?? 10;` is perfectly fine to use in javascript also. Just replace `int` with `let`.

#### `??` vs `||`

`??` should be preferred to `||` because it checks **only for nulls and undefined**.

All The expressions below are true:

```js
(null || 'x') === 'x' ;
(undefined || 'x') === 'x' ;
//Most of the times you don't want the result below
('' || 'x') === 'x'  ;
(0 || 'x') === 'x' ;
(false || 'x') === 'x' ;
//-----

//Using ?? is preferred
(null ?? 'x') === 'x' ;
(undefined ?? 'x') === 'x' ;
//?? works only for null and undefined, which is in general safer
('' ?? 'x') === '' ;
(0 ?? 'x') === 0 ;
(false ?? 'x') === false ;
```

**Asterisk:** Check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#browser_compatibility) and if you really need to support these other browsers use [babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Answer (score 6):

> I spotted half of the problem: I can't use the 'indexer' notation to objects (my_object[0]). Is there a way to bypass it?

No; an object literal, as the name implies, is an *object*, and not an array, so you cannot simply retrieve a property based on an index, since there is no specific order of their properties. The only way to retrieve their values is by using the specific name:

```
var someVar = options.filters.firstName; //Returns 'abc'
```

Or by iterating over them using the `for ... in` loop:

```
for(var p in options.filters) {
    var someVar = options.filters[p]; //Returns the property being iterated
}
```

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Note that this funny `for in` JS loop works only on object literals! It fails miserably on JS arrays (gives index) and JS Maps (gives `undefined`). Hope you don't forget that, lest you are in for a debugging surprise!  xP

Answer (score 2):

## Destructuring solution

Question content may have changed, so I'll try to answer thoroughly.

Destructuring allows you to pull values out of anything with properties. You can also define default values when null/undefined and name aliases.

```
const options = {
    filters : {
        firstName : "abc"
    } 
}

const {filters: {firstName = "John", lastName = "Smith"}} = options

// firstName = "abc"
// lastName = "Smith"
```

> NOTE: Capitalization matters

If working with an array, here is how you do it.

In this case, name is extracted from each object in the array, and given its own alias. Since the object might not exist `= {}` was also added.

```
const options = {
    filters: [{
        name: "abc",
        value: "lots"
    }]
}

const {filters:[{name : filter1 = "John"} = {}, {name : filter2 = "Smith"} = {}]} = options

// filter1 = "abc"
// filter2 = "Smith"
```

[More Detailed Tutorial](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-default-values)

[Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_destructuring) 92% July 2020