# Set a variable if undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I know that I can test for a JavaScript variable and then define it if it is `undefined`, but is there not some way of saying

```js
var setVariable = localStorage.getItem('value') || 0;
```

seems like a much clearer way, and I'm pretty sure I've seen this in other languages.

Comment: that is _not_ a test for "undefined", it's a test for "falsey"

Comment: Note that `localStorage.getItem()` will throw an exception if the user has disabled cookies (at least in Chrome), so you may want to wrap it inside a `try...catch` clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the construct x = x || y mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean)

Answer (score 380):

Yes, it can do that, but strictly speaking that will assign the default value if the retrieved value is *[falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)*, as opposed to truly *undefined*.  It would therefore not only match `undefined` but also `null`, `false`, `0`, `NaN`, `""`  (but *not* `"0"`).

If you want to set to default only if the variable is strictly `undefined` then the safest way is to write:

```
var x = (typeof x === 'undefined') ? your_default_value : x;
```

On newer browsers it's actually safe to write:

```
var x = (x === undefined) ? your_default_value : x;
```

but be aware that it is possible to subvert this on older browsers where it was permitted to declare a variable named `undefined` that has a defined value, causing the test to fail.

Comment: I'm surprised this pattern isn't included in more JS libs.

Comment: is there a downside to using `var x = (x === undefined ? def_val : x);` as the slightly longer `var x = (typeof x === 'undefined') ? def_val : x;`. Does the behavior differ?

Comment: @marco in older browsers it was possible for `undefined` to be redefined, causing the equality test to fail.

Comment: @Alnitak what is the best approach to use a similar syntax to the one that OP is using and still check for undefined?

Comment: @IvoPereira You can't use the `||` approach in a strict test for undefined, you have to use an explicit test for `undefined` with a conditional.

Comment: It does the trick but it is economically not advantageous as you have to write the variable name three times. an if ( x==undefined) {x = def_val} is clear and requires only one repetition. I think it is really worth adding a compact way. Something like |= (or any other convenient symbol to pair with the = meaning: assign if not already defined)

Comment: @a1an other languages have a "null coalescing operator" that doesn't have the (often unwanted) behaviour of `||=` where it matches any "falsey" value, and not just strictly "undefined" values.  JS unfortunately doesn't.

Comment: @Alnitak is there a list of those older browser somewhere?

Comment: The following option is better `var x = (x === void 0) ? def_val : x;` just because it's shorter.

Comment: Using `void 0` instead of `undefined` works around the old browser issue you pointed out.

Answer (score 168):

## Logical nullish assignment, ES2021+ solution

New operators are currently being added to the browsers, `??=`, `||=`, and `&&=`. This post will focus on `??=`.

This checks if left side is `undefined` or `null`, short-circuiting if already defined. If not, the right-side is assigned to the left-side variable.

#### Comparing Methods

```
// Using ??=
name ??= "Dave"

// Previously, ES2020
name = name ?? "Dave"

// or
if (typeof name === "undefined" || name === null) {
    name = true
}

// Before that (not equivalent, but commonly used)
name = name || "Dave" // Now: name ||= "Dave"
```

#### Basic Examples

```
let a       // undefined
let b = null
let c = false

a ??= true  // true
b ??= true  // true
c ??= true  // false
```

#### Object/Array Examples

```
let x = ["foo"]
let y = { foo: "fizz" }

x[0] ??= "bar"  // "foo"
x[1] ??= "bar"  // "bar"

y.foo ??= "buzz"  // "fizz"
y.bar ??= "buzz"  // "buzz"

x  // Array [ "foo", "bar" ]
y  // Object { foo: "fizz", bar: "buzz" }
```

[??= Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_logical_nullish_assignment) Oct 2022 - 93%

[??= Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

[||= Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment)

[&&= Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment)

Comment: Is it really a good idea to copy this answer to two other questions ([Replace a value if null or undefined in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62824506/4642212) and [Is there a “null coalescing” operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62824349/4642212))? Woudln’t it be better to VTC as duplicate or link to related questions in the comments?

Comment: The questions are all slightly different; as such so are the answers. The examples are consistent to improve inline context at a glance. Probably could have linked for more detail, but would have required an extra hop that may cause people to skip the solution

Comment: Note that some IDEs (NetBeans) detect `??=` as invalid syntax. Default auto source formatting will convert it to `?? =` with a space in between, which is invalid JS. Now to figure out how to customize the auto-formatter...

Comment: can't believe this isn't already supported, such a basic feature

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to be working with nested properties such as `router["GET"]?.["/admin"] ??= {"/admin": handler};`. Perhaps a deeper abstraction would be better.

Comment: It doesn't work on multiple depths with a `?.` operator because it won't fill in the missing layers, but it does work at any depth on a defined object. `a['b']['c'] ??= d` works if `a['b']` is defined

Answer (score 31):

**The 2018 ES6 answer is**:

```
return Object.is(x, undefined) ? y : x;
```

If variable x is undefined, return variable y... otherwise if variable x is defined, return variable x.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `Object.is` isn't any better than `===` in this case. "The === operator (and the == operator as well) treats the number values -0 and +0 as equal and treats Number.NaN as not equal to NaN." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) Doesn't matter here.

Comment: Even so, Trevor, you should always use Object.is() now instead of === as a force of habit.

Comment: I disagree. Know them both and use the appropriate one. In particular, use `Object.is` if both of the operands might be `NaN`.

Comment: If Object.is() works on 100% of the use cases, and === works on 98% of the use cases, why would you risk using === at all? For example: console.log(+0 === -0); // outputs true, while console.log(Object.is(+0, -0)); // outputs false -- which is better? Is negative 0 the same as positive 0? That's the question you have to ask yourself, but if you use Object.is(), you always know the answer. They are not the same, so an output of false is the correct and expected result.

Comment: The particular context here is always comparing to `undefined`. So `===` will work 100% of the time, not just 98%. The advantage of `===` being it is easier to read, especially at a glance, shorter and avoids an unnecessary method call. Personally I would only use `Object.is()` when the situation requires it and prefer `===` in all other cases.

Comment: Absolutely; if you're an experienced coder. Unless you accidentally forget an equal sign, in which case debugging why == isn't working somewhere is something I would never wish upon any developer. Better safe than sorry and always use Object.is(), The reason is was included in the spec was specifically to help developers write less buggy code.

Answer (score 29):

### ES2020 Answer

With the [Nullish Coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) Operator, you can set a default value if `value` is null or undefined.

```
const setVariable = localStorage.getItem('value') ?? 0;
```

However, you should be aware that the nullish coalescing operator does not return the default value for other types of falsy value such as `0` and `''`.

However, do take note of the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing). You may need to use a JavaScript compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to convert it into something more backward compatible. If you are using Node.js, it has been supported [since version 14](https://medium.com/@nodejs/node-js-version-14-available-now-8170d384567e).

Answer (score 13):

I needed to "set a variable if undefined" in several places. I created a function using @Alnitak answer. Hopefully it helps someone.

```
function setDefaultVal(value, defaultValue){
   return (value === undefined) ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

Usage:

```
hasPoints = setDefaultVal(this.hasPoints, true);
```

Answer (score 7):

In our days you actually can do your approach with JS:

```
// Your variable is null
// or '', 0, false, undefined
let x = null;

// Set default value
x = x || 'default value';

console.log(x); // default value
```

So your example WILL work:

```
const setVariable = localStorage.getItem('value') || 0;
```

Comment: Watch out for booleans.  It's easy to miss in a pinch but if option x is a boolean setting and the user sets it to false, it will move to the next operand because of the OR operator and always end up true.

Answer (score 6):

It seems more logical to check `typeof` instead of `undefined`? I assume you expect a number as you set the var to `0` when undefined:

```
var getVariable = localStorage.getItem('value');
var setVariable = (typeof getVariable == 'number') ? getVariable : 0;
```

In this case if `getVariable` is not a number (string, object, whatever), setVariable is set to `0`

Answer (score 3):

You can use any of below ways.

```
let x;
let y = 4;
x || (x = y)
```

in ES12 or after

```
let x;
let y = 4;
x ||= y;
```

Comment: This has [already been suggested](/a/62824667/4642212). `||=` does not set a variable if it’s merely undefined; it sets it if it’s falsy.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a FP ([functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)) fan, [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) has a neat helper function for this called [defaultTo](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#defaultTo) :

usage:

`const result = defaultTo(30)(value)`

It's more useful when dealing with `undefined` boolean values:

`const result2 = defaultTo(false)(dashboard.someValue)`

Comment: this is exactly `const result = value || 30;`, except is using an in-between function and +1000 bytes lib

Comment: @Adelin not true, it also handles falsy for boolean types. If you're using this lib already (as I am) then it's pretty useful, and terse

Answer (score 1):

`var setVariable = (typeof localStorage.getItem('value') !== 'undefined' && localStorage.getItem('value')) || 0;`

Comment: Will not also asign 0 if `localStorage.getItem('value'))` returns `false`

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this scenario today as well where I didn't want zero to be overwritten for several values.  We have a file with some common utility methods for scenarios like this. Here's what I added to handle the scenario and be flexible.

```
function getIfNotSet(value, newValue, overwriteNull, overwriteZero) {
    if (typeof (value) === 'undefined') {
        return newValue;
    } else if (value === null && overwriteNull === true) {
        return newValue;
    } else if (value === 0 && overwriteZero === true) {
        return newValue;
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

It can then be called with the last two parameters being optional if I want to only set for undefined values or also overwrite null or 0 values.  Here's an example of a call to it that will set the ID to -1 if the ID is undefined or null, but wont overwrite a 0 value.

```
data.ID = Util.getIfNotSet(data.ID, -1, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Works even if the default value is a boolean value:

```
var setVariable = ( (b = 0) => b )( localStorage.getItem('value') );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that for current javascript implementations,

```
var [result='default']=[possiblyUndefinedValue]
```

is a nice way to do this (using object deconstruction).