# How to set a default value for const?

Tags: javascript

I got a `const` in meteor containing `color` and `text` variables:

```
const exampleTemplate = (text, color) => ('
   Hello, this is your text:
   ${text}.
   I hope you liked it. And here comes your color:
   <span style="color: ${color}">Boom, here she is.</span>
');

const defaultColor = '#123456';
const firstColor = '#876543';
const secondColor = '#295736';

return exampleTemplate('I am a text example', defaultColor);
```

How can I define `defaultColor` as default if no other var is set? I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409641/javascript-set-a-variable-if-undefined) but I am not able to adopt its markup. I want to use `defaultColor` if the const `color` is `null`, `false`, `0`, `NaN` or `""`.

Comment: `const exampleTemplate = (text, color=defaultColor)` is best practice - not sure why it would be NAN, "", or false - the above case tests if not passed - you would have to check for these in the code - and also your template literal is incorrect - should be surrounded by back ticks unless Meteor uses a different templating engine - but assume this is es2015 syntax

Comment: "*I am not able to adopt its markup*" - just use `…${ color || defaultColor }…`.

Comment: `color` is not a `const`??? It's a function parameter (of an arrow function stored in a `const exampleTemplate` variable) and behaves just like a `var`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Default Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

```
const exampleTemplate = (text, color = defaultColor) => ('
');
```

You'll still need to do some type-checking for all of the conditions you mentioned though.