# What is a better way to assign variables to values of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is a better way to write this in JS

```
let foo
  if(bar) foo = bar.value
```

I am trying to avoid react error when bar is null if i use `const foo = bar.value`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a variable if undefined in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409641/set-a-variable-if-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: Also yes. I was looking for Optional chainning as answered by YohaiM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use optional chaining, look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
const foo = bar?.value
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the chaining operator if your node version is recent enough.

```js
const foo = bar?.value
```

Or the and operator to take the value of bar if bar isn't falsy.

```js
const foo = bar && bar.value
```