# how to replace undefined with a empty string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jspdf

I am using jsPdf. When a field has been left blank "undefined" is printed on the pdf. I would like to replace that with a empty string. I am trying to use a if statement but I am not getting it.

```
 doc.text(30, 190, "Budget : $");
    if ($scope.currentItem.JobOriginalBudget == "undefined") {

        doc.text(50, 190, " ");
    }
    else {
        var y = '' + $scope.currentItem.JobOriginalBudget;
        doc.text(50, 190, y);
    };
```

Comment: Just do `var value = $scope.currentItem.JobOriginalBudget || " "; doc.text(50, 190, value+'') ` Check for falsy value which could be `undefined, "", null, NaN, false, 0` etc.. Or use `angular.isUndefined($scope.currentItem.JobOriginalBudget)` for specific check, or even `angular.isDefined` for the opposite of previous

Comment: or expanding on what @PSL shows, create a simple helper function since a PDF likely has numerous of these to do and can write `getVal(var)` a lot easier than lots of comparisons

Comment: `var y = '' + ($scope.currentItem.JobOriginalBudget || '');`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`undefined` is a primitive value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.9). Instead of comparing against the identifier `undefined`, you're comparing against the 9-character *string* "`undefined`".

Simply remove the quotes:

```
if ($scope.currentItem.JobOriginalBudget == undefined)
```

Or compare against the `typeof` result, which *is* a string:

```
if (typeof $scope.currentItem.JobOriginalBudget == "undefined")
```

Answer (score 24):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011317/replace-a-value-if-null-or-undefined-in-javascript) I believe what you want is

```js
doc.text(50, 190, $scope.currentItem.JobOriginalBudget || " ")
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var ab = {
firstName : undefined,
lastName : undefined
}

let newJSON = JSON.stringify(ab, function (key, value) {return (value === undefined) ? "" : value});

console.log(JSON.parse(newJSON))
```

```html
<p>
   <b>Before:</b>
   let ab = {
   firstName : undefined,
   lastName : "undefined"
   }
   <br/><br/>
   <b>After:</b>
   View Console
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

simply remove the "== 'undefined'"

```
if (!$scope.currentItem.JobOriginalBudget) {
    doc.text(50, 190, " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If item is an Object use, this function :

```
replaceUndefinied(item) {
   var str =  JSON.stringify(item, function (key, value) {return (value === undefined) ? "" : value});
   return JSON.parse(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case

```
doc.text(50, 190, $scope.currentItem.JobOriginalBudget??"")
```