# How to loop through and print out correctly

Tags: javascript, html, json

I Know why I'm getting undefined but i have no idea how to solve.

Tried to put null, but it is taking in as a text

```
var text ='{"employees":[' +
                '{"name":"Tony","mobile":"99221111","email":"tony@json.com"},' +
                '{"name":"Linda","mobile":"98981111","email":"linda@json.com"},' +
                '{"name":"Patrick","mobile":"90902222","email":"patrick@json.com"},' +
                '{"name":"Isabella","mobile":"99552222"}]}';
    obj = JSON.parse(text);
    for(var i in obj.employees)
    {
        document.getElementById("table").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + obj.employees[i].name + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj.employees[i].mobile + "</td>" 
            + "<td>" + obj.employees[i].email + "</td></tr>";
    }
```

Hi, for Isabella there is no email, hence I'm getting undefined when I loop through to print out their details on html, however what I'm expecting is for the email portion to be empty in the table for Isabella. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: `"<td>" + obj.employees[i].email || '' + "</td></tr>";`

Comment: @Vai You should not answer in comment.

Comment: And, why not ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace undefined with a empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876247/how-to-replace-undefined-with-a-empty-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical OR (`||` in JavaScript), which will use the second value (empty string in this case) if the first value (email) is `undefined`:

```js
var text = '{"employees":[' +
  '{"name":"Tony","mobile":"99221111","email":"tony@json.com"},' +
  '{"name":"Linda","mobile":"98981111","email":"linda@json.com"},' +
  '{"name":"Patrick","mobile":"90902222","email":"patrick@json.com"},' +
  '{"name":"Isabella","mobile":"99552222"}]}';
obj = JSON.parse(text);
for (var i in obj.employees) {
  document.getElementById("table").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + obj.employees[i].name + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj.employees[i].mobile + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + (obj.employees[i].email || '') + "</td></tr>";
}
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```