# What does "||" mean in javascript (besides OR)?

Tags: javascript

I know that  `||` means `OR` that's easy. But recently I saw this piece of code :

```
var myArray = [['activity', 'none'] , 
               ['movies', 'activity'],
               ['theater','activity'],
               ['drama', 'movies'],
               ['comedy', 'movies'],    
               ['puppet', 'theater'], 
               ];

var nodes = {};
for (var i in myArray) {
    var child = myArray[i][0];
    var parent = myArray[i][1];
    var children = nodes[parent] || []; // what is this ? 
    children.push(child);
    nodes[parent] = children;
}

alert(nodes);
```

I am confused. `children` looks like it is an array because it has a `.push` method. But `var children = nodes[parent] || [];` points to :  `children` is boolean . .

Also, how can one compare an object and an empty array ? 
`var children = nodes[parent] || [];`

Thanks

Comment: It's [logical `OR`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_%28.7C.7C%29) there ; ).

Comment: you can use `||` to set a default value; in this case, an empty array (`[]`) is the default value for `children` if `nodes[parent]` is falsy.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011317/replace-a-value-if-null-or-undefined-in-javascript

Comment: If you feel that your specific confusion with this issue is not addressed by the duplicate I've used, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `nodes[parent]` is empty or null an empty array is assigned to children variable (for not beeing null).